# What is the Jewish understanding of the Holy Spirit?

Tags: christianity, ruach-hakodesh

Christians believe in the Holy Spirit. They believe that the Holy Spirit is the third hypostasis of the Trinity, and is thus 100% God. What Christians called the "New Testament" talks about the Holy Spirit a lot, and it was composed in a Jewish cultural context, which indicates that there was a general understanding of the Holy Spirit among Jews of the day.

How do Jews understand the concept of the Holy Spirit? I would predict that you don't believe he is God because you don't believe that God has a Triune nature. Perhaps you don't even believe the Holy Spirit is a person, and therefore it is inappropriate to refer to it as "he"?

I'm sure there are some references to the Holy Spirit in the Hebrew scriptures, but right now the only one that comes to mind is in the beginning of Genesis/Bereshit:

> **NJPS Genesis 1:1-2**  In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.  Now the earth was unformed and void, and darkness was upon the face of the deep; and the spirit of God hovered over the face of the waters.

Comment: I wasn't sure what tags to add. I added "Christianity" but I bet there's some more that could apply but I just can't think of. eg how do you write "Holy Spirit" in Hebrew?

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic. Essentially, the question is 'what is the Holy Spirit in Judaism?' and this is a subject on which our Sages have spilled no small amount of ink.

Comment: Alternatively, to make the question sound less Christian, it could be reworded to ask how Judaism interprets certain anthropomorphic verses (like Bereshit 1:2 cited in the question) which Christianity took in a more literal direction.

Comment: As mentioned by @Lee, there has been an enormous amount written about the anthropomorphization within the text of the Torah and Prophets, and substantial disagreement as well. Any answer would require a review of an enormous body of literature ranging from the Talmud itself to biblical commentaries and modern day authorities. I don't think it's "off topic," but "how do Jews understand X" is impossibly broad, especially for so contentious a subject...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky While this is a particularly esoteric and fundamental concept, virtually *every* question in both Halakhah and Mahshavah has produced "an enormous body of literature ranging from the Talmud itself to [Biblical] commentaries and modern day authorities". I don't think that disqualifies the question.

Comment: There is a Jewish concept called "[Ruach haKodesh](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=ruach+hakodesh)" which could be translated something like "holy wind" or so, but that doesn't mean it is in any way similar or related to the Christian "Holy Spirit". Neither "holy" nor "spirit" are such unique terms in religion, so this shouldn't be something surprising. Your example from Genesis is not this "Ruach HaKodesh" and your thinking it is the same Holy Spirit as in Chrisitanity is your Chrisitian background reading that in.

Comment: @Lee I didn't vote to close, but  questions along the lines I mentioned (how "Jews" understand things) have frequently been considered over broad according to MY guidelines. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle (1) I understand you wanted to give background on the subject of your question so you mentioned the beliefs of another religion although this is not appropriate for this site. (2) As an Orthodox Jew, I do not believe that there is a testament that is “new”. (3) You make an assumption that you “that there was a general understanding of the Holy Spirit among Jews of the day.” For example, I guess there was no general understanding of the trinity  among Jews of the day which did not stop its adoption.

Comment: I was torn about whether to close this as a comparative religion question but the reason I ultimately voted to close is because of the lack of significant evidence that such a concept exists in Judaism and lack of an explanation of what "Holy Spirit" is. You could ask "Christians believe the Holy Spirit is XYZ. Does Judaism believe that?" but when you ask if Judaism has some concept of <English expression here> it's essentially unanswerable unless that English expression is well-defined.

Comment: @Lee I saw your edit, but voted to leave closed in the review queue. The problem with this question is not the fact that the New Testament was mentioned, but that the Holy Spirit was not explained, as Daniel mentions in the comment above mine. `@TheIronKnuckle, I would be happy to vote to reopen if you were to [edit] your question to include a description of the phenomenon you would like to know Judaism's position about.